# Installing Apache Spark on Windows Server 2022

Tags: windows, apache-spark, hadoop

Environment Information:

OS: Microsoft Windows Server 2022 Standard Evaluation

Spark Version: version 3.4.0

Hadoop Version:3.3.1

I installed Hadoop and confirmed that it is working by executing basic commands:
hdfs dfs -put hi.txt / , hdfs dfs -get /hi.txt .
Also hdfs dfsadmin -report showed no errors.

**Error 1**

When I tried to run sparki benchmark, I am getting the error below:
ContainerExecutor: Exit code: -1073741515

Googling: This error indicates a missing DLL

I am not able even to seek further info because of the following error:

**Error 2**
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File C:/$$$App Log Path $$$/prelaunch.err does not exist.

**Steps Taken**
I download the C++ redistributable as suggested by some online posts as it could add missing DLL dependencies.

Comment: Hadoop doesn't run too well on windows, and is not a requirement for Spark... You can try in WSL2 (if that's available on windows server) or just run Spark code from an IDE without running extra processes

Comment: what about using docker images ? it'll be better, faster, more stable and easy to maintain

Comment: In my setup I need both Hadoop and Spark

Comment: And both can be run with Docker or in WSL2, or even a Linux VM, as mentioned.... Using Windows just isn't the best supported OS for these tools

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this.

The executable that starts an Apache Spark container is winutils.exe.  For some reason which could possibly include missing configurations or missing environment variable that I should have set, this executable does not look for DLL(s) in C:\Windows\System32 and its sub-directories.

Process Monitor, an amazing tool that helps debug such types of errors. You would see DLL(s) requested and the path.

I copied all C:\Windows\System32 dlls into hadoop/bin in addition to other DLL(s).